# Create and Update API for Project and Task (One to Many relationship) Django REST API (bulk create and update)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, one-to-many, bulkinsert, django-serializer

Does anyone have a good example of creating an API where I can create a project and add multiples tasks to it?

```
class Project(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Task(models.Model):

    priority = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    todo = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I would like to be able to create a project and at the same time provide a list of tasks for the project.

Json post would look something like this

```
{
name: "Project",
tasks: [
  {priority: "High", todo: "Create front-end page" },
  {priority: "High", todo: "Connect back-end " },
  {priority: "High", todo: "Deploy server " }
]
}
```

With this Json I hope to create project with name="Project name" and after creating project I would like to add the tasks which uses the project as foreign key.

From this API I hope to be able to project model with field name = "Project name" and creating the other 3 tasks model using given fields priority, todo, and project as a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Nested Serializers for this purpose. You can try the following code -

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['priority','todo']

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
tasks = TaskSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name','tasks']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        tasks_data = validated_data.pop('tasks')
        project = Project.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for task_data in tasks_data:
            Task.objects.create(project=project, **task_data)
        return project
```

You can read more about nested serializers [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)